# javascript formatting css in a innerhtml

Tags: javascript

```
   document.getElementById("days").innerHTML = document.getElementById("days").innerHTML + daynumber
   dayname;

   if(dayname.value==6 || dayname==0) 
   { 
   daynumber.style.boder("solid");
   }
```

Any idea the formatting why doesn't work?

Comment: Because (assuming `daynumber` is an HTML element) A) It's `border`, not `boder`, and B) It's a property, not a method. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ElementCSSInlineStyle/style

Comment: Hi. It's not super clear what you are trying to achieve. Can you elaborate on what you're trying to do? Also elaborate on what the issue is and give enough code to reproduce it

Comment: Hello, you ask a question is not understand by folk, please explain the question in details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without trying to guess what the function is meant to do, you gotta fix the border property, and set it equal to the intended value instead of call it like a method

Also it's "border" instead of "boder", also just the property "solid" usually doesn't do anything unless there are other hidden html rules somewhere that define the width and color, if not hey have to be added

Also, from the latter part of the code it seems `daynumber` is an HTML element since you are setting the style, yet in the beginning you are adding it to other HTML strings implying it is a string or number. Also in the if statement it appears dayname is an HTML input element since you are reading it's `value` property, yet in the second part of the if statement you are checking if it itself is equal to 0, implying it is a number, I'm guessing for the second part of that if statement you wanted to check the value again, also I'm guessing `daynumber` is div element or something similar, since borders usually aren't assigned to inputs unless they have some kind of custom border, so I'm guessing you intended to add the `innerHTML` property of daynumber to the other innerHTML property. Let me know if there was a different intention

```
document.getElementById("days").innerHTML = document.getElementById("days").innerHTML + daynumber . innerHTML
  

   if(dayname.value==6 || dayname.value==0) 
   { 
   daynumber.style.border = " 1px solid black";
   }
```